# 40 element array of digits to store integers as large as 40 digits each

Tags: c#

Can someone explain me what is this question really mean

Create a class HugeInteger which uses a 40-element array of digits to store integers as large
as 40 digits each. Provide methods inputHugeInteger, outputHugeInteger, addHugeIntegers
and subtractHughIntegers. For comparing HugeInteger objects, provide methods isEqualTo,
isNotEqualTo, isGreaterThan, isLessThan, isGreaterThanorEqualTo and isLessThanOrEqualTo

I am not asking for code , some explanation should be enough.

Basically i didn't understand this part

**"40-element array of digits to store integers as large
as 40 digits each."**

Comment: Imagine 1024 not being int x = 1024 but rather int[] x = { 1, 0, 2, 4 }; Except you're dealing with 40 elements and you need to encapsulate it and perform some math.

Comment: yeah, as anthony said. each digit an element of the array.

Comment: In the interest of sanity, the array would more likely be stored as `x = { 4, 2, 0, 1 }` as the 1's place would logically be the 0th element of the array and would grow upward from there. With a static 40-element array, it wouldn't matter, but you will have to pick an orientation and stick with it. Don't forget carrying and borrowing for adding and subtracting. For extra credit, overload the + and - operators. ;-)

Comment: Thanks all for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Well a digit is generally, in base 10, considered to be a single digit ( as it's not plural ) and that's 0 through 9

So the closest datatype to that is a byte ( as a byte gives you 2^8 - 1 as a max value )

Which suggests, if we suppose that a "digit" can be represented by a byte then we are looking for something like an array, of type byte, of length 40.

```
var arr = new byte[40];
```

Comment: @Thanks mimis for the explanation